# How can I forward traffic from a specific port to another in open-vswitch

Tags: networking, docker, virtual-machine, openvswitch

I am trying to setup an ovs as a transit switch. This would be used to create a data network for a docker container.

i.e. In the diagram below, I was able to add veth0-veth3 and veth100 to veth103 to the ovs. but I want to configure such that all traffic from veth0 goes to veth100 and vice versa. Similarly veth1-veth101, veth2-veth102, veth3-veth103 pairs.
One way it could be done was to use vlans, but if possible I wanted to avoid doing that. 
Is there a configuration possible that allows the pinning of ports as described above?

> ```
>                 Openvswitch              
>               +-------------+              
> veth0  +------+             +--veth100--
> veth1  +------+             +--veth101--
> veth2  +------+             +--veth102--
> veth3  +------+             +--veth103-- 
>               +-------------+
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done by the following command:

```
ovs-ofctl add-flow <Bridge> in_port=<src_Port>,actions=<Action>
```

In the `<Action>` put the destination port as follows:

```
output:destination_port
```